# Generic code not DBContext find not executing includes

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following method that I want to pass in an array of includes and have entity framework load and the associations passed in the expressions array:

```
    public static async Task<T> FindAsync<T>(this GSCMContext context, Expression<Func<T, bool>> match, , params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        var set = context.Set<T>();

        if(includes != null)
        {
             foreach (var include in includes)
             {
                set.Include(include);
             }
        }
        return await set<T>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(match);
    }
```

The problem is that the associations are not loaded in the same way as if I ran this code:

```
context.Entities.Include(a => a.association).Find(id)
```

I have no idea why my code does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are just ignoring the result of `Include` method. You should modify your method to match the one below:

```
public static async Task<T> FindAsync<T>(this GSCMContext context, 
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> match, 
        params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
        where T : BaseEntity
{
    IQuerable<T> query = context.Set<T>();

    if(includes != null)
    {
         foreach (var include in includes)
         {
            // Include returns result
            query = query.Include(include);
         }
    }
    return await query.SingleOrDefaultAsync(match);
}
```